# How should I override the equals method of an API class?

Tags: java, overriding, wrapper

I am using the Vector2 class of the libGDX API, and if I want to check the equality of two vectors I have to do the following:

```
Vector2 vectA = new Vector2(0, 1);
Vector2 vectB = new Vector2(1, 1);

if (vectA.x == vectB.x && vectA.y == vectB.y) {
   return true;
}
```

This is very uncomfortable and I am thinking about creating an equals() method for this scenario. Which should be the better to do:

1. Creating a wrapper for the Vector2 class with an equals(Vector2) method
2. Creating an EqualUtil class with an equals(Vector2, Vector2) method

The first would look better (in my opinion), but it may not be a 'nice' solution while the other is much cleaner but also a bit simplistic. Different ideas also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should.

In my opinion, it is better to create a Wrapper (and you should also override `hashCode()` to match the new behavior).

Not only doing so will result in more readable code, it will also allow you to use collections such as a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) or other methods that rely on the `equals()` behavior.

It also makes sense logically, because you are trying to create a method that gives data on the specific object - what better way to show it then to do it as an *instance method*?

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with, overriding both `equals()` as well as `hashCode()` method inside a `Vector2` class.

From Joshua Bloch **Item -9**

> Always override hashCode when you override equals

Edited:

Scroll down to page 45
[Page 45: Item-9](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=effective%20java&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bj_tUMynCImnrAfrvIDgCA&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=equals&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface CheckObject(){



  public abstract boolean and(CheckObject checkobject);
}



public abstract class AbstractObject()
    implements CheckObject
{

    public AbstractObject()
    {
    }

public abstract boolean and(CheckObject checkobject);
 protected void beforeObjectChecked(Object obj)
        throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
    }


public class EqualUtil extends AbstractObject {

private int point1;
private int point2;
}
protected EqualUtil(int point1,int point2){

this.point1=point1;
this.point1=point2;
}
public  boolean and(CheckObject checkobject){
    beforeObjectChecked(checkobject);
    return(this.getPoint1()==checkobject.getpoint1() && this.getPoint2()==checkobject.getpoint2()));

}


public int getPoint1() {
    return point1;
}

public void setPoint1(int point1) {
    this.point1 = point1;
}

public int getPoint2() {
    return point2;
}

public void setPoint2(int point2) {
    this.point2 = point2;
}
```

Now you can use it from Main Class

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper's are a good and understandable way to add in new behaviour when the original designers did not include it for some reason. Given that the original API class just uses the java.lang.object equals method, creating a wrapper seems a sensible option to me.

Comment: As mentioned above, you should also override hashCode too.